# Analyze Code Coverage throws error after tests are run

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I get the following when I try and Analyze Code Coverage using MSTest in 2012.  It happens on a new project and new tests as well.

```
Exception was thrown: Code Coverage Analysis engine threw exception(s):

Coverage file "xxxx" is invalid or corrupt.
```

Comment: I also have the same issue .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running code coverage analysis on VS 2012 throwing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642001/running-code-coverage-analysis-on-vs-2012-throwing-exception)