# Visual Studio unit test code coverage exception "file path of .coverage file is invalid or corrupt"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Im getting an error when I run unit tests code coverage. Everything passes but when I run analyze for code coverage in visual Studio it runs the tests but errors out when creating the coverages file.

Also its happening with solutions that I download that walk through setting up code coverage and also solutions that I've been able to run code coverage on in the past. I'm running visual studio 2012 ultimate. Any ideas ?

Error is

> Exception was thrown : Code Coverage Analysis engine threw exception
>   .. "file path of .coverage file" is invalid or corrupt

I've tried deleting everything in the coverage folder... I was also at update 4 to begin with so downgrading wouldn't make sense.

I've tried adding a local testsettings in solution items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running code coverage analysis on VS 2012 throwing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642001/running-code-coverage-analysis-on-vs-2012-throwing-exception)

Comment: yea its the same issue but old ... the guy who responded was running 2010 .. i already tried that one

Comment: also at update 4 .. not 1

Comment: You should include what you've already tried in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-apply update 4 choosing the *repair* option and see if that resolves the issue. I have seen other non related install *handicap* the update due to insertion of previous versioned assemblies. Reinstalling will bring all up-to-date for Visual Studio.

If not then create basic console application as a basic test project and see if the same happens. If it does try running studio with these startup options

```
devenv.exe /log

devenv.exe /safemode

devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

devenv.exe /installvstemplates

devenv.exe /resetsettings

devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

Check the [log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272.aspx) for possible issues.

Comment: re installing update 4 worked ... Something got really screwed up. Thanks.

Comment: @bdawg I had a Windows Phone Project and a non related Azure install killed the virtual Phone emulator seemingly out of the blue. Re-installing/fixing update did the trick as well.